# headers in multiple line to be made into one line

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an excel file which is having headers and its data in multiple line. I have attached the screenshot for further clarification.

I want my data to look like this. Can anybody help me with C# code or SSIS steps to do this.

**My Original data set:**

[image: My original data set]

**Desired Output:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output of a report, we have been using Monarch to get the data right before we work this in any other system. I feel your pain.

Comment: ya now I remember, my previous clients were using monarch software...but is there any other way by which we can do it :(

Comment: You can try excel macros but I have rotten luck with those.